# Parámetro de ruta en petición POST

Tags: api, post, rest

Tengo una petición de tipo POST (que devuelve un 204 No Content) cuyo propósito es ejecutar una acción de lectura y extracción de base de datos y publicar en un broker (una acción sin creación de recurso). El identificador del recurso a leer y extraer en base de datos se pasa como parámetro de ruta en la URI. Algo como:

```
/rutaejemplo/{identificadorrecurso}/accion
```

¿Es esto correcto o debería incluir ese identificador de recurso en el body de la petición? Algo como:

```
/rutaejemplo/accion

Con body:
{ 'id'='identificadorrecurso' }
```

He leído en la documentación de Microsoft que sí es una buena práctica, pero solo cuando se necesita crear un recurso de un recurso identificado concreto, pero es en el único lugar que encuentro esta premisa.
Gracias de antemano.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Si has dado con esta pregunta, aquí tienes la respuesta. La respuesta la encontré en el apartado de "best practices" de RESTful web API design de Microsoft (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/architecture/best-practices/api-design).

El parámetro de ruta **podrá utilizarse** siempre y cuando se añada un nuevo recurso que depende de otro (el recurso del que depende se identificará en la URI) o cuando la petición POST implique una acción sobre un recurso de una colección, el cual se identifica mediante un parámetro de ruta en la URI.

**No** podrá utilizarse como identificador del recurso que será creado por la petición POST; en este caso deberá ser identificado en el body de la petición.